# How to parse Embeddable Links from Markdown and render custom React Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, remarkjs, react-markdown

I want to embed Twitter tags from Markdown to Html. I am currently using react-markdown to render like below

```
import gfm from 'remark-gfm'

const content = `#Hello <br/><hr/> <p>Please check out this tweet</p><br/> <p>https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1378480731651981322</p>`

....

<Markdown
 plugins={[gfm]}
 children={content} / >
```

I hoped to be able to parse anything that starts with `https://twitter.com` so i could render a React Component for the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass a custom `a` component to `ReactMarkdown` that would handle links with your own logic.

```js
import Markdown from 'react-markdown'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'

const content = `
  # Hello
  Please check out this tweet: https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1378480731651981322
`

export default Index() {
    return (
        <Markdown
            remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
            components={{
                a: props => {
                    return props.href.startsWith('https://twitter.com') ? (
                        <CustomTwitterComponent url={props.href} /> // Render Twitter links with custom component
                    ) : (
                        <a href={props.href}>{props.children}</a> // All other links
                    )
                }
            }}
        >
            {content}
        </Markdown>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works spendidly !.  Spent the entire morning trying to look into react-shortcodes to render with regex.

Comment: @juliomalves  i am using exact same custom link renderer, but some url's are not getting caught by the renderer(meaning for some links the code for link inside renderer does not get called at all) and the link simply appears as text. Any idea why this can happen?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a URL that doesn't get caught by the link renderer?

Comment: This is outdated

Comment: @CodingLittle Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer to be compatible with the latest `react-markdown` version.